# MySQL query for a single row and get the value from it

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file that will update a table in MySQL. It will update all the done flags from 0 to 1 after a job has completed. I need to query the `done=0` starting from the lowest primary key (ID). After the job is done, I update the done=1 and move on to the next row. I have the following table :

```
--------------------
| ID | test | done |   
--------------------
| 1  | test1| 0    | 
--------------------
| 2  | test2| 1    | 
--------------------
| 3  | test3| 0    | 
--------------------
| 4  | test4| 0    | 
--------------------
| 5  | test5| 1    | 
--------------------
```

When I do the following query `SELECT test FROM mytable WHERE done=0 ORDER BY id ASC` it gives me all the test that have done flags that are 0, however, I want to start with the first and handle that first, then move on to the next one and so on. So I need a query that will show me just the first row. How can I do this?

Comment: append  `limit 1` to your query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is on the right track, since it already is sorting by ascending id. All you need to do is limit it to only returning the first result, if one exists. Just add `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query:

```
SELECT test FROM mytable WHERE done=0 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```